# Ubuntu Server / desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments, webserver

I'm new in the world of Ubuntu and I have some questions...

I have a server at my home and I would like host some websites myself.
I see there are ubuntu server but with this version is verry hard for me, it's only under command...   but in the past I use Ubuntu desktop and it's more easy.

To host websites, can I use Ubuntu Desktop or I'm in obligation to use Ubuntu server ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No-one that has good Linux Experience uses the Desktop Version to host Live websites, Its too Slow Compared to the Server. As for the worries you have about the command line, Ubuntu has made it so easy you only need to learn How to install and configure LAMP, SSH and SAMBA server. Then you use another Computer to do your HTML/PHP etc editing or connect to the Server via a terminal to do whatever while having all the benefits of a lighting fast Linux Web-server. Its Extremely Easy.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use the Desktop version. The server one is simply more streamlined and comes with certain packages installed by default. In the Desktop version, you will need to install things like apache (the webserver) yourself. So, it might take a few more steps to set up but it will work perfectly well.

You can find all the information you need on the official help pages:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use the server version if you don't want too. All packages available for server are also available on desktop (and vice versa). Server is more optimized for well, server loads since it doesn't run a desktop environment by default, and doesn't have many desktop apps you probably don't need anyway.